# Wordpress Theme of home page in two pages

Tags: wordpress, themes

So, i need to apply the main page theme of inspiro in two diferent pages, but wordpress only allows me to insert it in one page, sugestions?

Comment: You can make templates and use different pages, but at a time the home page will be one